# MS SQL Linked Server to HANA 2.0 - error 10 authentication failed

Tags: sql-server, sap-hana

I have some trouble setting up a linked server to a SAP HANA database.

On the SQL-Server machine (SQL-Server 2019) i installed the ODBC drivers and set up a 64 System DSN. When I click on the "Test Connection" it succeeds. Driver version is 2.04.167.62361

I then Setup the Linked server as Follows:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
   @server='SAP', 
   @srvproduct='HANA',  
   @provider='MSDASQL',   
   @datasrc='HANA64';  --> Name of the ODBC DSN
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
 @useself = 'FALSE', 
 @rmtsrvname = 'SAP', 
 @locallogin = NULL,
 @rmtuser = 'Readonly',
 @rmtpassword = 'my_pwd';
```

It creates the Linked Server. When I test the connection in SSMS I get:

> [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] General error;10 authentication
>   failed

All research on the internet did not get me further. Any Ideas?

My ODBC DSN Connection looks like follows:
[image]

Comment: How is your DSN configured? What are you doing for credentials? Is there anything on the HANA side logged about the failed authentication?

Comment: @AMtwo I added a screenshot of my DSN config. If I click on  Test connection and enter the 'Readonly' / 'my_pwd' user it says connection successful. Haven´t checked the HANAsSide, i have to look into it. Absolutely no experience with HANA